# Property 'type' is missing in type 'ChartComponent' but required in type 'ApexChart'

Tags: angular, typescript, types, charts, apexcharts

I got an error as you can see in the title:Property 'type' is missing in type 'ChartComponent' but required in type 'ApexChart'. When I tried anything else I get this error:

> Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ApexChart'.  Types
> of property 'type' are incompatible.  Type 'string' is not assignable
> to type 'ChartType'.

My code in html:

```
 <apx-chart[series]="series" [chart]="chart" [title]="title"></apx-chart>
```

Also tried like this in html:

```
 <apx-chart
  [series]="chartOptions.series!"
  [chart]="chartOptions.chart!"
  [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis!"
  ></apx-chart>
```

Code in ts.:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ChartComponent,
  ApexAxisChartSeries,
  ApexChart,
  ApexXAxis,
  ApexTitleSubtitle
} from "ng-apexcharts";
export type ChartOptions = {
  series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  xaxis: ApexXAxis;
  title: ApexTitleSubtitle;
};

export class InsightsComponent implements OnInit {
  series: any;
  title: any;
  @ViewChild("chart") chart: ChartComponent;
  public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;
constructor() { }
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          name: "My-series",
          data: [10, 41, 35, 51, 49, 62, 69, 91, 148]
        }
      ],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "line",
        width:500,
      },
      title: {
        text: "Frakture"
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"]
      }
    };
  }
```

I tried adding chart as any or undefined. Also, tried to add it as an interface:

```
export interface ChartOptions  {
chart: any;
```

}

Comment: you forget a double quote in your .html? `<apx-chart[series]="series" [chart]="chart` ..here.. `[title]="title"></apx-chart>`

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you, but it is still says the same error as the title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

html. code:

```
<apx-chart[series]="chartOptions.series"[chart]="chartOptions.chart"[xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"></apx-chart>
```

ts. code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ApexAxisChartSeries, ApexChart, ApexXAxis} from "ng-apexcharts";

export type ChartOptions = {
    series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
    chart: ApexChart;
    xaxis: ApexXAxis;
};

@Component({
    selector: 'app-insights',
    templateUrl: './insights.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./insights.component.scss']
})

export class InsightsComponent implements OnInit {
    public chartOptions: ChartOptions;
    title: any;

    constructor() {
        this.chartOptions = {
            series: [{
                name: 'ExpensesPerMonth',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

            }, {
                name: 'IncomePerMonth',
                data: [1600, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]

            }, {
                name: 'InvoicedPerMonth',
                data: [2600, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
                 
            }],
                xaxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                height: 250,
            },
        };
    }
```